# GeneXus Translation issues

Tags: genexus

I have used the GX translation tool for over 6 months, and suddenly the below issue appeared. Has anyone encountered the same, or perhaps could you please give me some advice on this?

The tool freezes once I try to import or export the file.

Add some translation -> Save -> Click "Tools" -> Click "Export Translation file" -> Display freezes

- Restart the PC -> nothing changed
- Uninstall the tool and try again -> nothing changed.

Comment: In order to have more details about this error, it can be helpful to paste here the stack trace from the Event viewer from Windows

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.